# Hide current table row on click using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, hide

I have a bunch of table rows such as:

```
<tr>
  <td>cell1</td>
  <td>cell2</td>
  <td><a href="action.php">cell3</a></td>
</tr>
```

When someone clicks the link in cell3 is there a way to hide the whole tr row? So the second they click that link in cell3 the whole tr is hidden?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a good place for [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), like this:

```
$("#tableID").delegate("td:nth-child(3)", "click", function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").hide();
});
```

By using [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) we attach *one* `click` handler to the `<table>` for all those third-column cells, and then use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to climb up to the `<tr>` to [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).  If you want it on the link instead, just change `td:nth-child(3)` to `td a`, the rest is the same.

Comment: nth-child is a CSS3 selector, so I dont recommend using it if you want backwards-compatibility.

Comment: I think jQuery doesn't directly use the underlying CSS3 selector, I might be wrong, but I would assume it should work even without CSS3?

Comment: @Seth: Does this look like CSS?

Comment: umm, yeah - it does look like CSS. jQuery uses CSS selectors for the majority things like nth-child(), last(), etc... Things like parent() and children() parse the DOM though.

Comment: @Seth: I've never seen CSS that can handle events. jQuery/Sizzle uses a javascript based CSS selector engine. When available, it uses the DOM API `querySelectorAll` method. When unavailable it emulates its behavior. It is all javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Just use simply jQuery and hide the parent.

```
$('td.hide_on_click').live('click', function(){
  // PICK ONE OF THESE:
  $(this).parent('tr').remove(); //completely destroy the tr (remove from DOM)
  $(this).parent('tr').hide(); //just hide it from the user
});
```

Remove the a tag. If you want it to have the "link appearance", add a css style for a something clickable:

```
.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}
```

then:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="hide_on_click clickable">delete</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

hi this is my solution

```
$(document).on("click", "td:nth-child(3)", function () {
      if (confirm("Are you sure ?")) {
          $(this).closest("tr").hide();
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup

```
$('td a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().hide();
});
```

Comment: This won't hide anything, since the *immediate* parent isn't a `<tr>` :)

Comment: Yes, I always seem to think that `parent('selector')` acts slightly differently to the way it actually (obviously) does.

Comment: -1 this doesn't do what he asked. this only works on the link. if the cell has massive padding, clicking in the cell will do nothing - they have to click on the link. moreover, it also applies to EVERY table he makes. i dont think he wants <tr>s disappearing on every link click within

Comment: Firstly I am answering the initial question `When someone clicks the link in cell3 is there a way to hide the whole tr row?`. And also my solution demonstrates the desired effect only, the questioner has obviously simplified the HTML, and thus I have provided a matching simplified answer.