# Hide table row onclick using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors, hide

I have a bunch of table rows such as:

```
<tr>
  <td>cell1</td>
  <td>cell2</td>
  <td><a href="action.php">cell3</a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="notes_row">
<td colspan="6">
<ul class="message warning no-margin" id="notes_box">
<li>Notes here</li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>cell1</td>
  <td>cell2</td>
  <td><a href="action.php">cell3</a></td>
</tr>
```

The class="notes_row" is only there if notes are present for the row above it. How can I hide the tr and if its there the tr with the notes_row class below it without affecting the other rows using jquery? So if someone clicked cell3 the tr that link is in is hidden then if there is a notes table row below it, it hides that as well.

Comment: You JUST asked a question similar to this - please don't abuse this community. read documentation and understand how jQuery works before asking people to write code for you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543155/hide-current-table-row-on-click-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a[href=action.php]').click(function(){  // ... or however you attach to that link
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');

    // hide this row first
    row.hide();

    // next, get the next TR, see if it is a notes row, and hide it if it is
    var nxt = row.next();
    if (nxt.hasClass('notes_row'))
      nxt.hide();

    // stop link
    return false;
});
```

I think... Going by memory here.

**EDIT**

Couple minor fixes, and a fiddle link to see it in action:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/E6zcV/

Comment: Get rid of `.hasClass()` (it returns a Boolean), and do `.next('.notes_row').hide()` instead. If the next row doesn't have that class, nothing will happen.

Comment: @patrickdw: caught that as I posted it. All fixed now (can you tell it's approaching my bed time?) Good looking out though, thanks. ;-)

Comment: @patrick, there should be an accept on this answer. If it isn't available right this second, it will be soon (I believe there's a delay to accepting giving others time to answer and not having people always take the first one they get (speed of answer is seldom synonymous with accuracy ;p)).

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good place for [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), it can be as simple as:

```
$("#tableID").delegate("a[href='action.php']", "click", function(e) {
  $(this).closest("tr").hide().next("tr.notes_row").hide();
  e.preventDefault(); //don't follow the action.php href
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/fZRTs/).  What this does is use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to climb up to the `<tr>`, [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) that row, select the [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) `<tr>` *if* it has the `.notes_row` class, and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) that as well.  Finally I'm adding a [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) on there so we don't actually navigate to `action.php` from the link itself.